# Add native view over Webview content

Tags: java, android, webview

Up to Android 26 I could addView on a WebView without any problem. 
With the correct LayoutParam my content would act just like a web content. It would scroll with the webview etc...

Since Android 27, the added content is displayed, but it does not scroll with the content, and I can't inspect the WebView view hierarchy anymore. 
Also the WebView report a child count of 0.

Anyone have some indication on this (private I understand) behaviour?